# how is (myActor ? q) async in following scalatra example?

Tags: scala, angularjs, akka, actor, scalatra

in this post [Angular.js with Scalatra](http://rockyj.in/2013/07/27/angular_and_scalatra.html) it is said that the http call is asynchronous.  I see that the call to the actor is done with:

```
myActor ? q
```

however in scalatra home page i see they encapsulate the call with AsyncResult see:

```
get("/"){
    new AsyncResult { def is = 
      Future {
        // Add async logic here
        <html><body>Hello Akka</body></html>
      }
    }
  }
```

is there a difference between the two? I understand that the first one is calling an actor which returns a future, does that mean that both calls are async?

can you elaborate a little more about how the synchronicity of

```
 get("/query/:key/:value") {
    contentType = formats("json")
    val q = Query(params("key"), params("value"), mongoColl)
    myActor ? q
  }
```

is the http thread released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both calls are async. 'get' will either return a result or timeout. The request will wait for some kind of reaction from the Actor in this case however.

The application will not lock up if a result is not returned because of the `protected implicit val timeout = Timeout(10)` at the top of the class (this will instruct `myActor ? q` to give up on a result after 10 seconds).

The second example is a pure future based approach in which the body of 'Future' performs a series of operations async and onComplete returns a result.

I suggest you read [Akka Actors documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/actors.html) for more details

Comment: Hi in myActor ? Is there any blocking? I understand from akka side no blocking but is there a blocking of a thread from scalatra side?  Or in other words is the new syncResult required In case of calling an actor with the above `?` notation?